# Thunar Custom Actions appear twice

Tags: debian, context-menu, xfce, debian-wheezy, thunar

I'm currently using Debian Wheezy (aka testing) with XFCE desktop environment and Thunar.
Almost all the custom actions I have created so far appear twice in Thunar context menu.

I'm not at my Linux PC right now, so I'm sure about image-*, text-*, audio-specific etc custom actions, but those created for directories (i.e. rabbitvcs, tortoisehg etc) are repeated twice.

Example:

```
(1) SVN commit
(2) SVN update
(3) SVN clean
(4) Mercurial commit
(5) ...
(1) SVN commit
(2) SVN update
(3) SVN clean
(4) Mercurial commit
(5) ...
```

Custom actions are created with `Directory` option checked and `*` extension (which is default).
I think it's somehow related to parent directory, which probably is considered as right-click subject as well.

This is just my supposition, actually I'm confused and this behavior seems very strange to me.